# Add Code and pre tags to include code sample to angular component template

Tags: html, angular

I was using `<code>` & `<pre>` tags in html pages to include code samples in my website...

**Like:**

```
<pre class="code">
// Host creation
public class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
  }

  services.AddTransient<IDataAccessLayer>(a => new DataAccessLayer(_config));
  services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();  
}
</pre>
```

The same pre tag when I use inside my angular component file its showing error for opening brace `{` and **'IDataAccessLayer' is not a known element**.

I replaced all my "{", "}" with `&#40;` and `&#41;`

Now the C# sample code inside `<pre>` is still showing error. Is there any way of displaying the sample code block in the component as I have multiple code block returning the html through function is not feasible.

| package | version installed |
| --- | --- |
| angular cli | 13.2.6 |
| TS | 4.5.5 |

Comment: you can use html sanitizers here, or use something like markdown to replace html back and forth that way errors with wrong html will be gone. cant help more without seeing angular side, where you are rendering output.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this lib   [ngx-highlight](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-highlightjs) ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).